# choose n largest elements in two vector

Tags: c++

I have two vectors, each contains n unsorted elements, how can I get n largest elements in these two vectors?

my solution is merge two vector into one with 2n elements, and then use `std::nth_element` algorithm, but I found that's not quite efficient, so anyone has more efficient solution. Really appreciate.

Comment: Do you want n elements or a single n-th element?

Comment: Is n near to N or is it very small compare to N?

Answer (score 1):

You may push the elements into `priority_queue` and then pop `n` elements out.

Comment: But this has N*log(N) complexity. The problem can be solved in O(N)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that n is far smaller than N this is quite efficient. Getting minElem is cheap and sorted inserting in L cheaper than sorting of the two vectors if n << N.

```
L := SortedList()
For Each element in any of the vectors do
{
  minElem := smallest element in L
  if( element >= minElem or if size of L < n)
  {
    add element to L
    if( size of L > n )
    {
      remove smallest element from L
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<T> heap;
heap.reserve(n + 1);

vector<T>::iterator left = leftVec.begin(), right = rightVec.begin();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (left != leftVec.end()) heap.push_back(*left++);
    else if (right != rightVec.end()) heap.push_back(*right++);
}

if (left == leftVec.end() && right == rightVec.end()) return heap;

make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<T>());

while (left != leftVec.end()) {
    heap.push_back(*left++);
    push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<T>());
    pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<T>());
    heap.pop_back();
}

/* ... repeat for right ... */

return heap;
```

Note I use *_heap directly rather than priority_queue because priority_queue does not provide access to its underlying data structure. This is O(N log n), slightly better than the naive O(N log N) method if n << N.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the "n'th element" algorithm conceptually in parallel on the two vectors quite easiely (at least the simple variant that's only linear in the average case).

1. Pick a pivot.
2. Partition (std::partition) both vectors by that pivot. You'll have the first vector partitioned by some element with rank i and the second by some element with rank j. I'm assuming descending order here.
3. If i+j < n, recurse on the right side for the n-i-j greatest elements. If i+j > n, recurse on the left side for the n greatest elements. If you hit i+j==n, stop the recursion.

You basically just need to make sure to partition both vectors by the same pivot in every step. Given a decent pivot selection, this algorithm is linear in the average case (and works in-place).

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm

**Edit:** (hopefully) clarified the algorithm a bit.

Comment: If you're lazy, you can write a simple iterator wrapper that "virtually" concatenates your arrays, and just keep using std::nth_element. It's probably faster to re-implement the algorithm for two arrays though.

Comment: could you give more further informations? About that iterator wrapper.

Comment: You write a class that behaves like an iterator to a vector, and that dereferences to an element in the first vector for the first n indices and to an element in the second vector for the next n indices.